# the @synchronized in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, synchronized

```
@synchronized(self.runningOperations) {                      line 1
 [self.runningOperations addObject:operation];               line 2
}
```

when I debug these code .at first it runs the line 1 ,then go to the line 2.it's all right,but after this ,it go to the line 1 again,then go to the line 2,then jump out the @synchronized.
but when I print the runningOperations,the first time it runs the line 2 code,the Object not add into self.runningOperations,it is added at the second time.
why it run twice,and why the Object add into self.runningOperations in the second time?

Comment: and `self.runningOperations != nil`?

Comment: I think first time operation object may not existing .

Comment: @trojanfoe I add it between line 1 and line 2,it also run tiwce, but the first time it didn't run the line 2 ([self.runningOperations addObject:operation]; ),so at first time self.runningOperations is nil,but the second time,it runs line 2 code, so at the second time,the self.runningOperations isn't nil.what case this?

Comment: You'll need to explain yourself better; I cannot understand what you mean.

Comment: @ernaidu yes, I add the if(self.runningOperations != nil) between line 1 and line 2,the first time operation object is nil,but the second time it's not nil.

Comment: Ok good take care of the object called operation .

Comment: do you even understand why you are using the `@synchronized` keyword here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coincidentally, I've just been debugging some code that happens to have an `@synchronised`.

I too observed the debugger follow the pattern of line1, line2, "hop back" to line1 then on as normal, as I stepped through. I didn't find this to be unusual however, I've see the debugger do far more unusual things.

My best guess is that the program, perhaps at a lower level is

- doing nothing with the lock at the start, but the debugger still goes through that line
- entering the synchronized code (at which point it is now critical to have obtained the lock)
- checking the lock
- then starting execution of the atomic code.

My best advice would be to ***don't take the debugger's output as gospel***. If you're in release it's almost guaranteed to be wrong and even in Debug, I've seen step throughs be highlighted in unusual orders, I can't say why for certain, probably just discrepancies between viewed code and compiled code.

Comment: +1 agreed. Add an `NSLog` statement to see if the execution really happens twice. Probably not.

Answer (score 0):

If `self.runningOperation` is ever `nil` it cannot be used for synchronization. Ensure it's initialized before calling `@synchronized()` on it.